# Как в javascript code передать объект класса в Laravel ? И в строке переменной передать {{route()}}

Tags: php, laravel, php7, laravel-5.8, laravel7

Подскажите, как лучше реализовать такой функционал... Использую карты Leaflet - которыми вывожу мероприятия(Маркеры) - которые получаю из JSON ответа - методом ajax - вот кусок кода

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://champion/forallgamesfront',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: "JSON",
    cache: false
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data);

    //тип иконки

    let LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
        options: {
            iconSize:     [38, 38],
            //shadowSize:   [50, 64],
            iconAnchor:   [22, 34],
            shadowAnchor: [4, 62],
            popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
        }
    });

    let greenIcon = new LeafIcon({
        iconUrl: 'assets/front/images/main/ball_icon.png',
        //shadowUrl: 'http://leafletjs.com/examples/custom-icons/leaf-shadow.png'
    });

    // Опционально для маркеров

    let markerOptions = {
        opacity: 1,
        icon: greenIcon,
    };

    for(let i = 0; i<data.length; i++){

        let allData = data[i];
        console.log(allData);
     

        L.marker([allData.Lat, allData.Lng], markerOptions).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("<strong>"+ allData.title+"</strong><br/><strong style='color: green'>"+ allData.start_game+"</strong><br/>" +
            "<a href='{{cформировать метод или роут для объекта User}}' class='btn btn-danger'>Принять участие</button>);


    }
```

В цикле for - методом .bindPopup() - вывожу html код и данные объекта Tournament(мероприятия) - которые приходят из JSON ОТВЕТА - Со страницы(http://champion/forallgamesfront).
Дальше я хочу, чтобы объект User - смог в данном мероприятии принять участие. И нужно сформировать динамический код, для каждого типа - который будет формировать правильный вывод роутов, ниже что нужно

Проблема в том, что если пользователь Авторизован - он уже User, но у $user может быть свойство ->is_admin == 0, значит он может принять участие, если же is_admin == 1, то нет. Если же Guest - значит не Авторизован, - и Для каждого типа Usera - данный участок кода ("Принять участие) с определенным маршрутом и методом{{ route(*) }}.

Буду очень благодарен!

Comment: Я ничего не понял... Вы используете фронтэнд фреймворк или блейдами выводите?

Comment: @doox911 - получается что мне в javascript код в этот -
(L.marker([allData.Lat, allData.Lng], markerOptions).addTo(mymap).bindPopup("<strong>"+ allData.title+"</strong><br/><strong style='color: green'>"+ allData.start_game+"</strong><br/>" +
            "<a href='{{cформировать метод или роут для объекта User}}' class='btn btn-danger'>(Принять участие/зарегистрироваться/ Вы уже участвуете)</button>))
- нужно передать в этот кусок динамический код, вместе с route'м - или методами, которые будут для каждого типа Usera формироваться отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

```
@if(Auth::check())
// Что видит гость
@endif

@if($user->is_admin)
// Что видит админ
@endif
```

Если же нужно и роуты при этом проверять, то вам понадобится middleware, который проверяет права пользователя на вход

Comment: это я знаю. Как передать этот текст {{route}} - в javascript код ?